# C++ Object Instantiation Error in NetBeans

Tags: c++, oop

I'm having a very strange problem with my code.
I have the following class:

```
    class Test
    {
        int a;
        string name;
     public:
        Test(){a = 0; name = "foo";}
        void setArguments(int number, string b){
            name = b;
            a = number;
        }
    };
```

And when I try to call the constructor using

```
    int main(void){
        Test a = Test();
        return 0;
    }
```

I can build the code, but can't run it. I can't even debug it. Any ideas of what's wrong?

EDIT 1: I'm starting to think that is a Compiler related problem. I'm using MinGW along with MSYS and the C++11 standard

Comment: Please post a test-case.

Comment: What do you mean by a test-case?

Comment: `Test a = Test();` refers to a function. Try using this `Test a();`

Comment: I got the following error in the netbeans output console: RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,511, total time: 105ms)

Comment: @Pacha You got that completely the wrong way around. `Test a();` is a function declaration.

Comment: @Pedro I mean some self-contained code that we can try to compile and reproduces exactly the problem you are trying to fix.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yeah you are right

Comment: `Test a;` use instead

Comment: @Pacha already tried. Didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Does this code even build?
There is no semicolon after `class` body. There is not closing `}` for `setArguments`.

Comment: Yes, you are right and there is syntax error in this program and hence it would not even compile. This works fine after putting }; at the end of the class defintion.

Comment: It didn't work for me... Got the Error RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,511, total time: 103ms)

Comment: Try inserting any random text anywhere. That should not compile. And you will probably get the same error...

Comment: The problem is that I can build the code. After inserting random text in the code, I can't build it anymore. If I remove it, I can build again, but I get the RUN FAILED error. When I comment out the          "Test a()" or any equivalents, I can run it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a C#/Java background, that is why you try to instantiate your object `a` using that syntax. You can solve your problem using the following:

```
int main(void){
    Test a;
    return 0;
}
```

Objects that are not pointers in C++ must always call the constructors when they are declared.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have in your `main` basically does following :

The temporary object gets copied using the copy constructor to `a`. A better way is to write the following to avoid temporaries: `Test a;`